# How do i declare a dynamic key in an object for a Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a structure like this

```
alerts: {
[symbol: string]: [
    {
     alert_price: number,
     price_when_set: number,
    }
  ]
},
```

how do i declare the above in a mongoose schema as the key value for the object is variable.
Can i just use `alerts: [Object]` or `alerts: [Schema.Types.Mixed]` and use all kinds of objects within? or is there a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well I guess, try it, and see if Mongoose complains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of testing, I figured that that was indeed the solution. You can just declare the path as a `Mixed` type by either declaring it as on of the following:

1. `Schema.Types.Mixed`
2. `Object`
3. `Mongoose.Mixed`
4. `{}`